# Missing template Jquery with rails 6 and respond_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm trying to render an ajax request to favorite an ads but a missing template error shows up as follow whereas I added the '''remote: true''' into the '''link_to''' and did the Jquery setup for rails 6 with yarn.

Here is the error message :

FavoritesController#update is missing a template for this request format and variant.
request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []

Here is my code :

javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("jquery")
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

controllers/favorites_controller.rb

```
  class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  def update
    favorite = Favorite.where(annonce: Annonce.find(params[:annonce]), user: current_user)
    if favorite == []
        Favorite.create(annonce: Annonce.find(params[:annonce]), user: current_user)
        @favorite_exists = true
    else
        favorite.destroy_all
        @favorite_exists = false
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.js {}
    end
  end
end
```

controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def favorite_text
        return @favorite_exists ? "Retirer des favoris" : "Favoris"
    end

    helper_method :favorite_text    
end
```

views/favorites/update.js.erb

```
$('#favorite_link').text("<%= favorite_text %>");
```

views/annonces/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to favorite_text, favorites_update_path(annonce: @annonce), id: "favorite_link", remote: true %>
```

Comment: If you config rails-ujs correctly your link to will send an ajax request with js format, in this case the error looks for html file instead, so I suspect you have js error. Please check in your browser console for any js error.

Comment: 406 not acceptable is the browser console error